# compile is obsolete android studio

Tags: java, android

Buenas tengo un problema ,cuando ejecuto mi app me sale el error de que compile es obsoleto y que debo cambiar por implementation cosa que ya lo hice pero me sigue saliendo no se cual es el error aqui dejo el codigo de mi gradle del app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.ucv.moviles.proyecto'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.6'



    implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

y mi gradle del proyecto es asi

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

y me aparece esto

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Answer (score 0):

el detalle es por la versión de google services en tu classpath, intenta actualizar de la versión

> 3.1.1 a 3.2.0

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
 }
}
```

Saludos